# CORS problem with Laravel Api based on Clean-Laravel-Api project

Tags: api, cors, laravel-8

I'm trying to make and api service based in  [gentritabazi01/Clean-Laravel-Api](https://github.com/gentritabazi01/Clean-Laravel-Api) and larapi with Laravel8. I can't solve the problem with CORS when i make request from different servers to my api . The related is the following:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://dev.......com/users' from origin 'http://segu........com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Since 2 days ago, i was reading documentation from CORS and Laravel and any solution solve my problem. I tried creating a middleware and add the necessary headers:

```
//Infrastructure\Http\Middlewares\Cors
    <?php
    use Closure;
    class Cors
    {
      public function handle($request, Closure $next)
      {
        return $next($request)
           //Url a la que se le dará acceso en las peticiones
          ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
          //Métodos que a los que se da acceso
          ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE")
          //Headers de la petición
          ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*"); 
      }
    }
```

I tried to using the package [Fruitcake](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors) from  laravel, like is used on base proyect.

```
//Infrastructur/Http/Kernel.php
    class Kernel extends HttpKernel
    {
        /**
         * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
         *
         * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $middleware = [
            \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
            \Infrastructure\Http\Middlewares\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
            \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        ];
```

I tried to add the headers missed in index.php file on /public folder.

```
//public/index.php
use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset = UTF-8');
```

Someone knows how to solve it? I can add more code if was necessary.

Comment: what is your laravel version ,cause laravel 8 comes with cors middleware  already

Comment: My laravel version is laravel8

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, i find a solution.
I removed all related with cors in my project and i added this in public/web.config file:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

i write this inside system.webServer markup and my project starts to work again.